# Apache won't start

Tags: apache2, https

This started for an unknown reason about two weeks ago.

```
# apache2ctl start
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I was running Ubuntu 15.10, and in the meanwhile upgraded to 16.04, which appears to not have affected the issue.

```
# cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf 

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>


# netstat -tlnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2013/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1972/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1972/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1972/sshd
```

I've been using [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for HTTPS on my site for some time.

How can I debug the issue, and what information is relevant to find the cause?

Comment: Something is keeping your ports 443 busy already - look up what is actually listening at it with `sudo netstat -tlnp`

Comment: I've added the output to my post. Do I understand correctly that my ssh server is hogging the port? Any idea what could have caused that and how to fix it?

Comment: Ye your sshd seems to use it. Look into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` there should be ports specified, remove it then restart the service and it should be free.

Comment: That's great, let me just write a suitable answer for future people having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port is being used as suggested by "(98)Address already in use".
You can list your ports that are being listened to and which programs use it with:

`sudo netstat -tlnp`

Once you found the culprit you have to adjust the settings for that specific service to make the port free again.
In your case it is 'sshd' the ssh server which is keeping it.

You can adjust its settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Afterwards restart the ssh service and your port should be available for apache again.